# Why my laptop can't detect wifi?

Tags: networking, 20.04, wireless, bluetooth

My laptop has Ubuntu Linux 20.04. I can't turn off Bluetooth (if I turn it off, Airplane Mode turns on)
My laptop can't even detect the mobile hot spot?
My wireless is TP link
It could be a laptop problem, a software problem, or a hardware problem?

Comment: Could you help us help you by providing: (1) the terminal output of `sudo lshw -c network` (2) `sudo lspci` (3) `sudo lsusb`. With this, it may be possible for someone to offer a solution that works 

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the information requested by @matigo, plus the terminal output of `rfkill list`.